# jQuery(...).resizable is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-plugins, gantt-chart

I revised my question.

I cloned all of the files for this plugin, sorted and connected them correctly.

I have //= `require libs/ganttView` in my application.js file

However I get `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).resizable is not a function`

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery (...).validate is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704999/jquery-validate-is-not-a-function)

Comment: As with the linked question, you're missing a javascript plugin file, probably

Comment: sorry for this but what is a plugin file? does it come from cloning the git hub of the plugin? or something else?

Comment: there a few files I have them all and they are connected. for instance if i remove //= require libs/ganttView i get an error ganttView does not exist. when its there i get an error from the js file. i believe these are the plugin files you mentioned

Comment: Have you read the section on dependencies here: https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView and looked at the examples here: https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView/blob/master/example/index.html

Comment: Yes thank you! I am using jquery-ui 1.11.4 and jquery 1.11.2
I added 
//= requirejquery-ui/resizable
//= require jquery-ui/draggable
to application.js

Comment: Now I have no console errors and draggable is working but resizable wont. They should both be working on the same column.